# Executing Sitecore PowerShell script programmatically - Sitecore path not resolving

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am calling the powershell script programmatically using Sitecore Command.. ScriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart() ... Inside the script I have written following script:

```
$settingItemId = "/sitecore/content/XXXX/Settings/Setting"
$settingItem = Get-Item $settingItemId
```

It is throwing error:

```
Get-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\sitecore\content\XXXX\Settings\Setting' because it does not exist.
At line:122 char:16
+ $settingItem = Get-Item $settingItemId
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\sitecore\con...zation Settings:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
Cannot index into a null array.
```

adding C:\ drive..

Can someone help me here?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Get-Item -Path "master:\content\xxx"`

Comment: Yes. It is working.

but it is not working when I am trying Get-Item -ID "<guid>".. in this case what can I do .. please suggest

Comment: `Get-Item -ID GUID -Database "master"` ?

Comment: This is working from powershell console... but not working programmatically.

Comment: Do you run it from windows powershell? Or how do you execute your code?

Comment: No.. I have created a Sitecore command.. On the execute method I have created an object of ScriptSession and using this object making a call to the powershell script.

Comment: Where is the Command being used? Sounds like you are working against the module when there are integrations available to do this. The book outlines the required syntax for the commands.

Answer (score -1):

I see 2 problems with your approach.

1. First problem is related to the way you are trying to get the item. You need proper syntax like Get-Item -Path "Path" or Get-Item -ID "GUID". This has already been explained by Marek in comments
2. Second problem is you are running the powershell script stored in a string variable in C# code directly using ExecuteScripts. It can be error prone and you wont be able to change it at runtime. I would recommend to test the script in Powershell console and then save the script as an item in Sitecore using /sitecore/templates/Modules/PowerShell Console/PowerShell Script template. Once that is done, you can execute your powershell script in C# using below code -

   ```
   using (ScriptSession scriptSession = ScriptSessionManager.NewSession("Default", true)){
   Item speScriptItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("path-or-id-to-spe-item");
   string script = speScriptItem["Script"];
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
       scriptSession.ExecuteScriptPart(script);    }
   ```